# Converting ordered array into Binary Tree : Runtime Error in the code

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert an ordered array into a binary search tree with minimal height. I am getting an runtime error. Been at it for hours but couldn't figure out the error. Please help.

```
 #include <iostream>

struct node
{
    int value;
    node* left;
    node* right;

};

node* minimalheight(int* array,int start,int end)
{   
    node* x = new node;
    if(start == end)
    {
        x->value = array[start];
        x->left = NULL;
        x->right = NULL;    
    }

    else
    { 
        int midpoint = (start+end+1)/2;
        x->value = array[midpoint];
        x->left =  minimalheight(array,start, midpoint);
        x -> right = minimalheight(array, midpoint,end);
    }
    std::cout << x->value<<std::endl;
    return x;

}

int main() {

    int foo [5] = { 2,16,40, 77, 12071 };
    node* head= minimalheight(foo, 0, (sizeof(foo)/sizeof(foo[0]))-1);

}
```

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: @appleapple Just a runtime error.

Comment: I forgot to reedit it. It's still giving the runtime error. @KillzoneKid

Comment: @Useless You get runtime errors due to lots of other reasons. https://www.quora.com/What-causes-run-time-errors-in-a-C++-program .           I am not able to figure my mistake.

Comment: You have infinite recursion, what is expected output?

Comment: @Useless Thanks for the link. That was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If start is 0 and end is 1, midpoint gets calculated to 1, and it recurses infinitely at this line:

```
x->left =  minimalheight(array,start, midpoint);
```

The runtime error you are getting is probably when memory runs out from creating too many new node objects.

Comment: @MartinCook Thankyou. That was the problem. It's working fine now.